# Spring Data Rest Saving after Access Denied

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I have a application built with Spring Data Rest and I put a @PreAutorized to required an authentication to save. When a user without permission tries save an entity, he receive an access denied, however the change is saved.

```
PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "categories", path = "categories")
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public interface CategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Category, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or (#category.businessAccount.id == principal.businessAccountId && "
    + "hasAuthority('MODULE_FINANCE_AND_ACCOUNTING_WRITE'))")
    @Override
    @Modifying
    <S extends Category> S save(@Param("category") S file);

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or (#category.businessAccount.id == principal.businessAccountId && "
    + "hasAuthority('MODULE_FINANCE_AND_ACCOUNTING_WRITE'))")
    @Override
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Category c set deleted = true where c.id = :#{#category.id}")
    void delete(@Param("category") Category category);

}
```

How can I avoid save after this access denied?

Comment: Spring Data JPA? This is a managed entity and if you change it it will be automaticallly persisted to the database, no explicit call to save is needed. If you want to enforce a save you have to detach the entity before modifying it and afterwards call save.

Comment: I'm using Spring Data Rest, I have a Repository that provide the endpoints without controller or service, with it I just request a post or patch http to save. The Spring validate permissions, but however the access is denied and all changes are done. I beleave it is something with rollback or @Transactional, but I don't know what

Comment: As stated the entity is retrieved, modified and saved. It is a managed entity and thus changes are automatically flushed to the database. You don't need the call to save (which Spring Data REST does). You can try to disable the open entitymanager in view stuff `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` and see if that helps.